# How do I get the DICOM files from the DCM4CHE database

Tags: node.js, dicom, dcm4che

I'm trying to get the dcm4chee dicom from pacsdb database, some say it's in the instance table in the inst_attrs column which is a blob and I've been converting it to base64 to get the DICOM, but I have doubts if it's inst_attrs is the column.

I'm sorry for my English

Comment: What is the difference to this question (put by you as well):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680294/how-to-get-dicom-files-from-the-dcm4chee-database-with-node-js ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get dicom files from the dcm4chee database with NODE.JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680294/how-to-get-dicom-files-from-the-dcm4chee-database-with-node-js)

Comment: I've already removed it, someone who can help me? Please =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract some of the DICOM attributes from the DB, like the bit allocated DICOM attribute ([How DCM4CHEE stores the bits allocation information of DICOM image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923653/how-dcm4chee-stores-the-bits-allocation-information-of-dicom-image)), but the actual image data (from which you could make a JPG or PNG) is stored on the file system.

The location on the system can be looked up in the DB, but I don't believe the actual pixel data is stored in the DB.

Comment: Thank you! Then I will just have to refer to the server path where the dicom are located without doing conversions o.o thanks!

a question; I already tried to do the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923653/how-dcm4chee-stores-the-bits-allocation-information-of-dicom-image query! Then I have to assign those data + dcm if I want to display them in a dicom viewer?

Comment: The files on the file system should be DICOM format. They should include everything needed.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what it would be like to make the difference between the dicom of each patient?

Comment: https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Database+Table+Descriptions should give you the database schema information you need. Basically, If you're looking for a particular patient, find the appropriate patient entry in the DB, use the patient key to get the associated studies, use the study key to get the series, use the series key to get the instances, and finally use the instance key to get the files. With the files you can look up the path. Otherwise, you're left parsing the archive folder manually, which won't be fast once you have a good number of files.

Comment: One thing to note - the DICOM files are in the file system, but they may not contain the latest up-to-date information. If any of the study attributes are changed in DCM4CHEE, then it happens in database only and the file on disk is left as is. Updated data is inserted into the file on the fly when it is retrieved through DICOM interfaces. Therefore I suggest using actual DICOM query/retrieve or WADO to get the files and not go fishing in the DB and filesystem. According to PACS vendors and developers I've talked to - almost all PACS work like this and do not update DICOM files on disk.

Comment: That is a very good point, Tarmo R. Getting just the pixel data is likely safe, but the actual header information should be gathered from the DB (or better yet, DICOM Q/R).